# Saiku community edition

Tags: pentaho, olap, cubes, saiku

I'm a new user in OLAP. I've installed PENTAHO. I can create new "olap cubes" with pentaho and I'm able to see the cubes,  using Saiku trial plugin, installed using pentaho marketplace.

Now I've installed Saiku community edition.

I'd like using Saiku community edition but I'm not able to create a new cube.

How can I create new cube using Saiku commuity edition?

I've read to use Saiku Schema Designer but I don't find the community edition or how can I install saiku community edition inside of pentaho ?

Comment: You should augment your question with the steps that you've tried plus any scripting methods.

Answer (score 0):

To you create a new cube in Saiku CE standalone mode, you need create a data source in Admin console (http://wiki.meteorite.bi/display/SAIK/Data+Source+Management).

The Schema Designer plugin is for version Enterprise, then you need install [Saiku EE](http://www.meteorite.bi/products/saiku/download) get a [license](http://licensing.meteorite.bi/login) for use it. Schema Designer not work in Pentaho, because it use Mondrian 3 and Saiku EE standalone work with Mondrian 4.

See more about Schema Designer here:
http://wiki.meteorite.bi/display/SAIK/Creating+schema+using+Saiku+Schema+Designer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pentaho schema workbench](http://community.pentaho.com/projects/mondrian/) create a Schema file.Then create a dataSource file.Finally,put schema file in foodmart folder,put datasource file in saiku-datasources folder.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers. @king: I've created a Schema file with pentaho schema workbench with his dataSourcefile TESTY10. Inside of Pentaho works well. Now I've put schema file TESTY10.mondrian.xml  in the folder C:\saiku-latest\saiku-server\data where there is the file FoodMart4.xml. The database is MYSQL, where is datasource file in Pentaho ?